# How to prevent phishing sites from being uploaded on shared server?

Tags: security, cpanel, phishing

We have more than 1000+ clients are having websites using various CMSs.
Mainly using Wordpress and Joomla, These sites are getting hacked and phishing sites are uploaded.
Please let us know how shall we prevent it.

We already have maldet running on the server. But it doesn't detects many phishing folders as it is mainly in html format.

Answer (score 0):

What steps did you take, security wise? 
I don`t think that, as a hoster,  you can 100% prevent hacks/phishing/Xss for client sites as these attacks exploit client-level vulnerabilities (i.e. if client uses [some WP plugin which has vulnerabilities](http://packetstormsecurity.org/files/111319/wpdeans-shell.txt), there is little you can do about it).

What you can do is:

A.) Try to isolate each client to eliminate spill overs. This means - separate everything as much as you can (user data/ site resources and ect)

B.) Offer some form of client level protection (as an added service) to provide a solution, at least for some. I work at a security company (Incapsula) and we work with such hosting partners/re-sellers and I know that many others do so too.

C.) Raise awareness, if your clients use Joomla and WP, find out what are the common threats and inform your client about them. Notify about new patches/version and provide updated links and so on...

Hope this hepls

Answer (score 0):

What result shows may not be phishing but one thing I noticed about the phishing site is that there are many folders with 32 character long and these folders are many. Inside each folder you may find phishing  content. Use following command to find the folders with 32 character long name and scan manually to check if it is phishing or not.

```
#find /home*/*/public_html/* -type d -name "????????????????????????????????" > phishing.txt
```

You are free to use other techniques and can share if you like.